# Can we define the external composition • from V×F to V instead of F×V to V in the definition of vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the definition of vector space we multiply the scalar with the vector from left. Does it make sense if we multiply the scalar with the vector from right?

Comment: Do you want your scalar multiples to be on the left or right of your vectors?

Comment: In general we have seen the scalar multiplication of a vector from left. But is it possible to define it from right?

Comment: Yes.  It hardly makes a difference though.

Comment: See here:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't end up making a difference because fields are commutative. Just the notation reverses.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are some helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have just read the article, I have only one confusion regarding the fact that as Module is the generalization of vector space is it always true that if a certain property holds in the generalized space the property will always hold in the parent space ? Say for example , Lebesgue integration is the generalization of Riemann integration, but there are some functions which are Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes - every vector space is a module, but not conversely. Specifically, a module is a vector space iff its ring of scalars is in fact a field.